# How to count occurrences of pairs of data in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe loaded:

```py
         ColA     ColB
0           3        3
1           4        5
2           4        5
3           5        4
4           5        3
5           5        3
6           4        3
7           5        4
8           5        4
9           3        4
10          5        5
```

And I want to count the number of times distinct pairs of data occur. For example the pair (5,4) should have a count of 3, (4,5) should have a count of 2, and so on. What I ultimately want is a third column whose row entry is the count of the number of times the pair in ColA, ColB occurs:

```py
         ColA     ColB  Count
0           3        3      1
1           4        5      2
2           4        5      2 
3           5        4      3
4           5        3      2
5           5        3      2
6           4        3      1
7           5        4      3
8           5        4      3
9           3        4      1
10          5        5      1
```

I've tried creating a new column for the pairs using `df['Pairs'] = (df['ColA'],df['ColB'])`, thinking that then I could use the `.value_counts()` method on the resulting column, but I get the error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`.

Thanks for any insights you can provide.

**EDIT:** Clarified that I don't want to just view the counts, i want to incorporate them into the dataframe as a new column.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.ColA, df.ColB)`?

Comment: `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
`

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my original post, so i added that i don't want to just see the counts, I want to include them as a new column in the original dataframe. I'm not sure how I can use crosstab or groupby to do that.

Comment: Found the answer in the duplicate question (which didn't show up until i posted my question!). Thanks.